# Getting NaN when concatenating one-hot encoded dataframe and training dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am tring to use the OneHotEncoder in sklearn for the kaggle dataset [fish market](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aungpyaeap/fish-market). The dataset has several columns but only one categorical column, which is 'Species'. It has seven categories, so the output should be a 7 digit binary sequence for each sample. The output of encoded_df seems fine as well as the training dataset. However, when i try to concatenate them together, it has several NaN in the DataFrame. Can anyone please explain this to me?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Load the dataset
fish_df = pd.read_csv('Fish.csv')

# Splitting the data
X = fish_df.drop('Weight', axis=1)
y = fish_df['Weight']
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

# Define the columns to be encoded
categorical_cols = ['Species']

# Initialize the OneHotEncoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

# Fit and transform the categorical columns
encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(encoder.fit_transform(X_train[categorical_cols]))

# Concatenate the encoded features with the original features
X_train_trial = pd.concat([X_train.drop(categorical_cols, axis=1), encoded_df], axis=1)

X_train_trial
```

I tried to concatenate the two dataframes together along axis=1 and there are NaN in the dataframes.
[The image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnEf.png)

Comment: You have NaN because not all combinations align, you should `fillna(0)`